# ssh fails with pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to create session: File exists

Tags: docker, openssh

I have a situation where an outside `ssh` repeatedly (in a fast loop) connects to an OpenSSH daemon inside a Docker container that is based on Debian 10.5. Authorization is via an authorized key in `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` that enforces execution of a specific script also inside the container by way of [command restriction](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/authorized_keys/openssh#command=%22cmd%22) with `command="..."`.

What I observe is that most connections succeed but some (few) fail with this error in `/var/log/auth.log`:

> pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to create session: File exists

What does this indicate and which file is meant? I have come across recipes for resolving similar issues (also with "Failed to create session"), but not yet this on (with "File exists"). So how can I further diagnose and then resolve the issue at hand?

Answer (score 1):

Check the values of MaxSessions and MaxStartups in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

You may be running into either a session limit or a connection limit.

If you have control over the external script, fix it.  Instead of making repeated connections in a tight loop, either add a delay in the loop, or better yet, open a single connection and send multiple commands across it. Tight-looping an entire connection is very inefficient.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why wrong (presumably too low) values for `MaxSessions`/`MaxStartup` could cause an error message such as `File exists`? BTW no, I don't have control over the external script.

Comment: Not really.  It was just a suggestion on something to check.  I work in some large environments with zillions of ssh connections and I've seen connection limits cause Linux to give some bizarre errors.  There are also reports of trouble running sshd within containers.  If you really want to dig into it, within the container, run an strace on sshd until it fails and then look at the data to see what file it tried to create that resulted in the "file exists" error.  Changing the parameters I suggested is an easy test to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thx for the additional suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

`File exists` can come from https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/20956

It may or may not be related to having a lot of opened sessions in /run/systemd/sessions/.